# Switch or something else

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am making some game application about Janitors. It's in the early stage, and so far I am proud on it, however as time passes by my code is becoming really messy, so I decided to come over and ask for any help to solve/remake/implement this code in another way without so many cases. I was thinking about implementing some design pattern, however I am not sure which one. Any help is appreciated.

```
bool JanitorApp::key(unsigned char key)
{
if (MainApp::key(key)) return true;

switch(key) {
case 'Q': case 'q':
    current[0] = NULL;
    status[0] = "Stationary";
    return true;
case 'W': case 'w':
    current[0] = &cleans[0];
    status[0] = "Cleaning";
    return true;
case 'E': case 'e':
    current[0] = &eats[0];
    status[0] = "Eating";
    return true;
case 'R': case 'r':
    current[0] = &guards[0];
    status[0] = "Guarding";
    return true;

case 'A': case 'a':
    current[1] = NULL;
    status[1] = "Stationary";
    return true;
case 'S': case 's':
    current[1] = &cleans[1];
    status[1] = "Cleaning";
    return true;
case 'D': case 'd':
    current[1] = &eats[1];
    status[1] = "Eating";
    return true;
case 'F': case 'f':
    current[1] = &guards[1];
    status[1] = "Guarding";
    return true;

      case 'Z': case 'z':
    current[2] = NULL;
    status[2] = "Stationary";
    return true;
case 'X': case 'x':
    current[2] = &cleans[2];
    status[2] = "Cleaning";
    return true;
case 'C': case 'c':
    current[2] = &eats[2];
    status[2] = "Eating";
    return true;
case 'V': case 'v':
    current[2] = &guards[2];
    status[2] = "Guarding";
    return true;
}

return false;}
```

Comment: What exactly is "wrong" with this code?  Design patterns help reduce complexity by removing recurring patterns in your code.  Is this the only switch statement of this nature in the application?  If so, then applying a design pattern to remove switch statement is likely to result in more code and less clear of an intent.

Comment: The thing is, it's not. There are so many other switch statements, that I need to deal with it in some way. DP is one of the things that has got on my mind, however, if there exits any other thing that will help me to lower lines and make my code looks more pleasing, then it would be nice to propose here.

Comment: You really don't have much choice when it comes to performing a particular action based on keyboard input.

Comment: Having many switch statements does not mean you can apply a design pattern.  You must have a common structure to extract.  You might want to post some related code as an example so that we can see the structure.  Without that, it's really hard to answer you question without a lot of guessing.

Comment: @CodyGray: yes you have a choice.  You can bind actions or commands to key strokes and dispatch in a loop instead of a switch statements.  There are many ways to deal with this problem, but the switch statement is often a lot more concise than writing all this dispatching code.

Comment: I don't see how "binding actions or commands to keystrokes and dispatching in a loop" is much different than a switch statement. Perhaps I'm not imaginative enough, or the difference is incredibly inconsequential. I also don't know how you would achieve such "binding", but maybe I'm handicapped by the environments I usually work in.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking at the Command pattern. The Replace Conditional With Polymorphism refactoring might also be of interest.

Comment: Command pattern would be a nice solution, however could you give some example of the replace conditional with polymorphism refactoring? If so, this would be really nice.